# MySQL Cpanel Cron Job to backup Database, VIEW tables are not backed up. Solution?

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

so I have got a cron job script which does a backup of my database. At the moment it is functioning properly. The only issue is that the VIEW tables are not working in the backup when I try to import the sql file.

Is there a solution to this problem?

This is the cronjob script I am using:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u Current User -p'Password' databaseName > /home/cpanel-username/db_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M`.sql
```

EDIT

I tried to add a suggestion as given by someone which changed the cronjob script into this:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u  -p'' database --all-databases --routines --triggers --no-data > /home/cpanel/db_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M`.sql
```

did I misplace it? When I tried to import the sql that was outputted into my local I got an error.

```
16 errors were found during analysis.

Variable name was expected. (near " " at position 6)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 17)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 25)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 36)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 43)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 62)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 70)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 84)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 92)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 98)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 109)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 128)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 136)
Unexpected character. (near "[" at position 154)
Unexpected character. (near "]" at position 162)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "Usage" at position 0)
SQL query: Copy

Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS] For more options, use mysqldump --help;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa' at line 1
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/will-mysqldump-command-also-backup-all-the-views-that-are-present-in-db-or-there

Comment: @ErgestBasha do you know how I can integrate those into the cronjob script I have?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing mysqldump with below parameters. This makes sure the dump comes with view:

```
--all-databases --routines --triggers --no-data
```

You can also try to backup view using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as below:

```
mysql --skip-column-names --batch -e 'select CONCAT("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ", TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME, "; CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ", TABLE_SCHEMA, ".", TABLE_NAME, " AS ", VIEW_DEFINITION, "; ") table_name from information_schema.views'
```

Comment: where do I put this code @Dexter? Do I add this in my cronjob?

Comment: Do I add this inside of the cronjob command or create a new one?

Comment: Add it your script with mysqldump statement.